# "Is it true?" or "Does it true?"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I always get confused about:

- Is it true?
- Does it true?

Where and when should I use one or the other? In other words, when should I pose a question using *is* and when should I pose it using *does*?

Comment: sємsєм, is "does it true?" the way to say it in your language?

Comment: @Tristan In my native language Arabic verb to do means, mainly, to make something. The typical example: to do homework. Also in my native language asking, or talking about, for being something we use undeclared verb to be.
In other words, in Arabic there is no asking without a tool of ask, like what, how, where, etc. However, one may, rarely, ask without tools but it will be depend on the style of speaking.

Comment: I hope that in questions closed because it is too basic and in the close message you regard a link to one, or more, of the  standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll use "Does it x" when "x" is a verb (action word). Use "is" otherwise.

Comment: ...which is to say the one should never say 'Does it true?'.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment as to why it was downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

"Is it true?" is an appropriate rejoinder to the statement "His testimony is very convincing!"  An appropriate response would be, "[But] is it true?"

"Does it true" is not ever used in English.  The following sentence, is, however:

> "Does his testimony **ring** true?"

In other words, does the person's testimony *sound* true.  The word "ring" suggests a bell that rings clearly and distinctly; it rings true.  Truth can ring true.  By the same token, however, it can also ring untrue or false.  ("To ring false" is not a saying in American English, by the way.)

Some people are better liars than others, so one needs to be careful when trying to "read" people.

Answer (score 1):

"*Does it true* ..." is just an incorrect use of the phrase "Is it true ..." and seems to be popular in **slang/ teen lingo**.

*Does it true* is wrong, ungrammatical in formal writing and does not mean 'is it true'.

Fun:

- > I heard that the [separated] memory space will be put into the coming Java SE 8, does it true?
- > My dictionary says me that "throw off the scent/track" has an identical meaning. So, does it true or the answer with the "scene" is not correct?
- > … does it true that validome (xhtml) is more strict (up to date) than w3c x/html validation?

[From various online sources]